# Why is my Mail clipboard separate from everything else?

Tags: copy-paste

When I copy text from the terminal, I can paste it into the terminal with no problem.  I can also paste it into Firefox or TextEdit.

When I try to paste it into my Apple Mail, I get:

```
Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)
```

This is something I had in my clipboard a while back—days ago.  That day, I was having trouble pasting into Firefox when I copied from Terminal (and instead got the same text noted above).  But it doesn't seem localized to Terminal after all.

Right now when I copy text from Apple Mail, I can paste that text back into Apple Mail or into anywhere else.  But text copied from anywhere but Apple Mail can't be pasted into Apple Mail; attempting to do so will instead paste into Apple Mail the same text that was last copied *in Apple Mail*.

I don't even know where to start to try to debug this or see what is causing it.  How can I fix this?

(I'll post the output of any diagnostic commands that anyone can suggest.)

Comment: If cmd/v doesn't work, try ctrl/y instead. Let us know what happens.

Comment: @Tetsujin, it is very mysteriously working again...but I only posted this question after it happened for the *second* time, so I expect it will come back at some point.  When it does, I'll try Ctrl-y and report what happens.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: @Tetsujin, it just happened again.  Ctrl-y pastes some other text that I had just *deleted* in the Mail app itself, while Cmd-V pastes the last text I had *copied* in Mail.  But I can't paste text from LibreOffice to Mail, and I can't paste text from Mail to LibreOffice.  Actually it looks like the *Mail* clipboard is the system-wide one, since I can paste from Mail into other places.  I'll try restarting LibreOffice.